# EXTJS 4.2 Pagination issues

Tags: extjs, pagination, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a grid in which pagination implemented using xtype: 'pagingtoolbar'.When i include

```
bbar: {
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                pageSize: 2,
                store: store,
                displayInfo: true,
                plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager(),
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: {
                        fn: function(component) {
                            component.down("#refresh").hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

in my code .My grid comes like this [image: Pagination not working /grid not displayed properly]

But when I comment out/exclude the paging toolbar code,my grid comes like [image: Grid properly shown without pagination] as required but without pagination....How to make pagination working for my grid?

My Current code is

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager', {

    requires: ['Ext.ProgressBar'],
    /**
     * @cfg {Number} width
     * <p>The default progress bar width.  Default is 225.</p>
    */
    width   : 225,
    /**
     * @cfg {String} defaultText
    * <p>The text to display while the store is loading.  Default is 'Loading...'</p>
     */
    defaultText    : 'Loading...',
    /**
     * @cfg {Object} defaultAnimCfg
     * <p>A {@link Ext.fx.Anim Ext.fx.Anim} configuration object.</p>
     */
    defaultAnimCfg : {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'bounceOut' 
    },  

    /**
     * Creates new ProgressBarPager.
     * @param {Object} config Configuration options
     */
    constructor : function(config) {
        if (config) {
            Ext.apply(this, config);
        }
    },
    //public
    init : function (parent) {
        var displayItem;
        if (parent.displayInfo) {
            this.parent = parent;

            displayItem = parent.child("#displayItem");
            if (displayItem) {
                parent.remove(displayItem, true);
            }

            this.progressBar = Ext.create('Ext.ProgressBar', {
                text    : this.defaultText,
                width   : this.width,
                animate : this.defaultAnimCfg,
                style: {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                },
                listeners: {
                    el: {
                        scope: this,
                        click: this.handleProgressBarClick
                    }
                }
            });

            parent.displayItem = this.progressBar;

            parent.add(parent.displayItem);
            Ext.apply(parent, this.parentOverrides);
        }
    },
    // private
    // This method handles the click for the progress bar
    handleProgressBarClick : function(e){
        var parent = this.parent,
            displayItem = parent.displayItem,
            box = this.progressBar.getBox(),
            xy = e.getXY(),
            position = xy[0]- box.x,
            pages = Math.ceil(parent.store.getTotalCount() / parent.pageSize),
            newPage = Math.max(Math.ceil(position / (displayItem.width / pages)), 1);

        parent.store.loadPage(newPage);
    },

    // private, overriddes
    parentOverrides  : {
        // private
        // This method updates the information via the progress bar.
        updateInfo : function(){
            if(this.displayItem){
                var count = this.store.getCount(),
                    pageData = this.getPageData(),
                    message = count === 0 ?
                    this.emptyMsg :
                    Ext.String.format(
                        this.displayMsg,
                        pageData.fromRecord, pageData.toRecord, this.store.getTotalCount()
                    ),
                    percentage = pageData.pageCount > 0 ? (pageData.currentPage / pageData.pageCount) : 0;

                this.displayItem.updateProgress(percentage, message, this.animate || this.defaultAnimConfig);
            }
        }
    }
});

function getcumulative()
{

    var familyTable;
    var classTable;
    var orderTable;
    var phylumTable;
    var superkingdomTable;
    var genusTable;

    var counter = JSON.parse(reportData);
    for(var i=0; i< Object.keys(counter.levels).length ;i++)
    {
         var field=[];   
        var columnList = [];
        var minwidth=0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width;
        var noofitems=Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length;
        var actualwidth=(0.54*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width)/noofitems;
        if(minwidth>actualwidth)
        {
            actualwidth=minwidth;
        }
        columnList.push({
            xtype:'gridcolumn',
            text: "Sample v/s Feature",
            dataIndex : "Sample v/s Feature",
            width:0.1*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
            columnLines: true,
            locked:true});
        field.push("Sample v/s Feature");
        for(var p=0;p<Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length;p++)
        {

                columnList.push({
                    xtype:'gridcolumn',
                    header: counter.levels[i].samples[p].name,
                    dataIndex : counter.levels[i].samples[p].name, 
                    width:actualwidth,
                    columnLines: true});

                field.push(counter.levels[i].samples[p].name);

        }
        var mydata=[];
         for(var p=0;p<Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples[0].features).length;p++)
        {
            var s=[];
            s.push('<b>'+counter.levels[i].samples[0].features[p].name+'<b>');
            for(var j=0; j< Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length ;j++)
            {
                s.push(counter.levels[i].samples[j].features[p].count);
            }
            mydata.push(s);
        }
         var Store1 = new Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            autoLoad: false,
           pageSize : 2,
            fields: field,
            data: {
                    count:mydata.length,
                    data:mydata
                },
                proxy:{
                    type:"memory",
                    enablePaging: true,
                    data:mydata,
                    reader: {
                        type: 'array',
                        root: 'data',
                        totalProperty: 'count'

                    }
                }          
        });
        /*store.load({
             params: {
        // specify params for the first page load if using paging
                  start: 0,          
                  limit: 2
                     }
                 });*/

        var table = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            hidden:true,            
            id : counter.levels[i].name+'_ID',
            store: Store1,
            columns: columnList,
            columnLines: true,
            width: 0.64*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
            height: 0.5*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,



         /* bbar: {
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                pageSize: 2,
                store: Store1,
                displayInfo: true,
                plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager(),
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: {
                        fn: function(component) {
                            component.down("#refresh").hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }*/

        }); 

        if(counter.levels[i].name=='family')
        { 
           familyTable   = table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='order')
        { 
        orderTable=table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='phylum')
        {
        phylumTable=table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='class')
        {
        classTable=table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='genus')
        { 
        genusTable=table;
        }
        else if(counter.levels[i].name=='superkingdom')
        {
        superkingdomTable=table;
        }
    }
    Ext.getCmp('genus_ID').show();

var panel1= {
xtype:'panel',
layout:'vbox',
width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
height: 0.927*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
title:'<center>Levels</center>',
items:[{
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Genus',
    id:'button1',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Genus</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Family',
    id:'button2',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Family</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        }
       ,
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Class',
    id:'button3',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Class</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Order',
    id:'button4',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Order</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Phylum',
    id:'button5',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>Phylum</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').hide();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Superkingdom',
    id:'button6',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('tablepanel').setTitle('<center>SuperKingdom</center>');
        button.up('#main').down('#tablepanel').show();
        button.up('#main').down('#genus_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#family_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#class_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#order_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#phylum_ID').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#superkingdom_ID').show();

    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Export to CSV',
    id:'button7',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.16*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    handler:function(button)
    {
       JSONToCSVConvertor(counter, 'GeMS_Report', true);

    }
        }

        ],
        listeners : {
        afterrender : function(panel) {
            var header = panel.header;
            header.setHeight(0.038*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height);
        }
    }
};
var tablepanel= {
    xtype:'panel',
    title:'<center>Genus</center>',
    id:'tablepanel',
    style: 'border: solid Blue 1px',
     width: 0.64*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    height: 0.538*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
   closable:true,
   closeAction:'hide',
   items:[genusTable,familyTable,classTable,orderTable,phylumTable,superkingdomTable],
   listeners : {
        afterrender : function(panel) {
            var header = panel.header;
            header.setHeight(0.038*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height);
        }
    }
};

var sidepanel={
    xtype:'panel',
    header:false,
    id:'sidepanel',
    bodyStyle: "padding: 120px;",
    width:0.84*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    height: 0.927*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    items:[tablepanel]
}

var cumulative = {
    xtype:'panel',
    id:'main',
    title: '<center>Cumulative Report</center>',
    layout:'hbox',
    width:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    height: 0.965*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [panel1,sidepanel],
     listeners : {
        afterrender : function(panel) {
            var header = panel.header;
            header.setHeight(0.038*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height);
        }
    }
};
    return cumulative;
}


 function JSONToCSVConvertor(counter) 
    {
      var zip = new JSZip();

        for(var i=0; i< Object.keys(counter.levels).length ;i++)
            {
                var CSV = '';
                var row1="Sample v/s Feature"+',';
                  for(var p=0;p<Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length;p++)
                  {
                    row1 += counter.levels[i].samples[p].name + ',';
                  }
                  row1.slice(0, row1.length - 1);
                  CSV += row1 + '\r\n';
                  var row2="";
                  for(var k=0;k<Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples[0].features).length;k++)
                         {
                           row2 +=counter.levels[i].samples[0].features[k].name + ',';

                            for(var j=0; j< Object.keys(counter.levels[i].samples).length ;j++)
                            {

                            row2 +=counter.levels[i].samples[j].features[k].count+ ',';
                            }
                            row2 +='\n';
                            row2.slice(0, row2.length - 1);
                        }
                         CSV += row2 + '\r\n\n';
                          var fileName = "";
        var title=counter.levels[i].name;
        fileName += title.replace(/ /g,"_");   
         zip.file(title+".csv", CSV);
      /*  var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
        var link = document.createElement("a");    
        link.href = uri;
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = fileName + ".csv";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);*/
            }
            var content = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
    saveAs(content, "Cumulative_Levels_Report.zip");
    /*var content = zip.generate({type:"base64"});
    window.location.href="data:application/zip;base64," + content;*/

    }
```

[image: No error on console but still no data in grid displayed on using paging toolbar]

Comment: hello, sorry I was busy and could not test your problem to help. try to remove plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager(), line in your code. xtype:'pagingtoolbar'  do not require that. check if there is any error in your browser console

Comment: @LightNight 1.When i removed plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager(),grid is diplayed with no data ,same as in 1st image 2.When i remove both  plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager() and  xtype: 'pagingtoolbar ,grid comes as in image 2 but with no pagination bar,what could be the problem....any solutions?

Comment: is there any javascript error in consol?

Comment: @LightNight there is no error on the console....

Comment: you are generating everything dynamically, it's hard to track reproduce your problem. can you give  `reportData` variable value?

Comment: @LightNight thanks a lot,I have successfully resolved my problem successfully,Actually i was calling my script in body tag of my xhtml page,When i called it from head tag,my problem was resolved............by the way,thanks a lot for helping me.....you really helped me a lot during this whole EXT JS grid development for my project...thanks again